# change text color and size of a ListView in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

how I can change text color and size of a ListView without use custom adapter.. by kotlin language in android studio.

Comment: You have to provide some effort before people can help. That's how it works on this community.

Answer (score 1):

> how I can change text color and size of a ListView without use custom adapter

If you're using some of the built-in layouts (like `simple_list_item_1` for example) for you list items, you could define a custom theme that overrides the attributes you care about.

For example, `simple_list_item_1` is defined as a TextView whose properties are set from various theme attributes:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

So you can define a custom style for your text view:

```
<style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <!-- Other Attributes -->
</style>
```

Then use this style to override the attributes the layout is pulling from:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textAppearanceListItemSmall">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">32dp</item>
    <!-- Other Attributes -->
</style>
```

In general, if you're using a built-in layout, use the source code to see how it's defined. Generally, the properties of the layout are set via theme attributes that you can override in your own theme.

See [the documentation on styles and themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) for more info.

Hope that helps!